# How do I get a second element in a list and append it to different list

Tags: python, list, append, element

I have a list that contains student ID's and their scores. I am wanting only the scores to be appended to a different list but every time I try to only print the second element it gives me the whole line (student id and score). How would I go about doing this?

```
[['10000', '43\n'],
 ['10001', '26\n'],
 ['10002', '43\n'],
 ['10003', '57\n'],
 ['10004', '100\n'],
 ['10005', '57\n'],
 ['10006', '55\n'],
 ['10007', '60\n'],
 ['10008', '37\n'],
 ['10009', '30\n'],
 ['10010', '50\n'],
 ['10011', '17\n'],
 ['10012', '59\n'],
 ['10013', '57\n'],
 ['10014', '27\n'],
 ['10015', '6\n'],
 ['10016', '49\n'],
 ['10017', '30\n'],
 ['10018', '57\n'],
 ['10019', '56\n']]
```

Comment: It is a list of list? Could you post your student id with mark list?

Comment: Where's the code you came up with?

Comment: `score= [int(student[1].strip()) for student in student_list]`

Comment: this is all the code I have written so far

`filename = "small_marks.txt"
def letter_grade(num):
    letter = None
    if num < 35:
        letter = 'E'
    elif num < 50:
        letter = 'D'
    elif num < 65:
        letter = 'C'
    elif num < 80:
        letter = 'B'
    else:
        letter = 'A'
    return letter`

Comment: `try:
 f = open(filename)
 s = f.readlines()
 f.close()
except:
 print("ERROR: there was a problem reading the file.")

else:
 print("SUCCESS: file read!")


f = open(filename)
s = f.readlines()

student = []
for i in range(0,len(s)):
 student.append(s[i].strip("\n"))

for s in student:
  data = s.split("\t")
  print(data)

converted_grades = [letter_grade(num) for num in student]
print(converted_grades)`

Comment: `data = int(data)
print(data)

def num_to_letter(data):
    def letter_grade(data):
        letter = None
        if data < 35:
          return "E"
        elif data < 50:
          return "D"
        elif data < 65:
          return "C"
        elif data < 80:
          return "B"
        else:
          return "A"
        return letter
    return [letter_grade(data) for num in data]`

Answer (score -1):

```py
def get_ids(lists):
    score_list = list()
    for lis in lists:
        score = lis[0]
        score_list.append(score)
    return score_list


list_of_lists = [
    ["10000", "43\n"],
    ["10001", "26\n"],
    ["10002", "43\n"],
    ["10003", "57\n"],
    ["10004", "100\n"],
    ["10005", "57\n"],
    ["10006", "55\n"],
    ["10007", "60\n"],
    ["10008", "37\n"],
    ["10009", "30\n"],
    ["10010", "50\n"],
    ["10011", "17\n"],
    ["10012", "59\n"],
    ["10013", "57\n"],
    ["10014", "27\n"],
    ["10015", "6\n"],
    ["10016", "49\n"],
    ["10017", "30\n"],
    ["10018", "57\n"],
    ["10019", "56\n"],
]

print(get_ids(list_of_lists))
```

What was done;

1. Created a function to get the id list;
2. Split the list by comma.

Comment: this was super helpful but what I'm wanting is the scores, not the ID's :/ what would I have to change to do this? Because I tried to run it with `print(score_list)` but `score_list` wasn't defined...

Comment: My bad, when you run this code you will get score_list, I put the wrong function name, in fact you will receive the scores. Just copy and paste like snippet. And share your result !